# Different CSS result of Google Chrome in Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: html, css, windows, google-chrome, ubuntu

I have used a `div` tag in my code:

```
<a href="#"><div class="field btn half green" id="register-btn">ثبت نام</div></a>
```

And the CSS code for this tag is:

```
.field {
    position: absolute;
    width: 205px;
    left: 22px;
    color: #eaeaea;
}

.btn {
    height: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.half {
    width: 101px;
}

#register-btn {
    right:22px;
}
```

But the result is very different in Google Chrome on Windows and Ubuntu (There is an extra padding on Windows). How can I fix that problem?

[image]

Comment: 1. For debugging purposes, please see if it still does it with English text and let us know. 2. Also please try line-height instead of padding to see if you can the desired layout that way.

Comment: @MartinCapodici - The problem persists even with an English input (using font-family: Arial)

Comment: Try the line height then e.g. see my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljnufjs1/

Comment: @MartinCapodici Thank you, Man. the problem went away after using `line-height`. plase answer the question and let me accept your answer. By the way, what is the reason of this problem with `padding`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using line-height instead of padding.

```
.btn {
    line-height:40px;
...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ljnufjs1/

Not only will this fix the problem, but it is a better fit for what you are trying to achieve than padding.

I am not sure why padding doesn't work, but it may be because the text isn't a block element so gets treated differently.